# how to get image type from imageview (android)

Tags: android, image, imageview

i am working on an wallpaper app in which i am receiving images from `internet` in `GridView` and `Full Screen ImageView`.

i want to save `ImageView` loaded image using its real `image type`, but i don't know how to get `image type from ImageView`.

example: if loaded image is `JPEG` or `PNG` then how do i get image type.

this is my code that i am using to save image as JPEG:

```
int intHeight = fullImageView.getHeight();
            int intWidth = fullImageView.getWidth();

            String dirname2 = "/Wallpapers HD/";

            File myDir2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath() + dirname2);

            myDir2.mkdirs();

            String fname2 = "image" + intHeight + intWidth + ".jpeg";
            File file2 = new File(myDir2, fname2);

            if (file2.exists())
                file2.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(_context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should keep track of this yourself. In the code you use to set the ImageView's drawable, you could apply a tag to the view to store that data:

```
String[] parts = fileName.split(".");
String extension = parts[parts.length-1];
imageView.setTag(extension);
```

And retrieve it from the view later:

```
String ext = (String) fullImageView.getTag();
```

Comment: Where are you loading the images from the internet into the ImageView?